# databases and data not saving ~Linux QubeOS~

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

when i create a postgresql database and create tables and columns and even insert data into the columns. I cant restart my machine without losing the created databases and all the data.

i have tried changing a coupe things in the configuration file but nothing helped.

I also have to reset the password for postgres everytime I restart my machine. I mainly use mongodb I am just learning postgreSQL just so I can use it if I ever need to in the future. I am runing a Linux machine QubesOS. I have a few problems like this useing QubesOS. every tutorial I watch everybody uses Macs. Which a mac seems good and all kinda a mix between windows and linux The best of both worlds. Easy package installs and terminal control but I dont want to trade my linux machine for a Mac I would much rather just fix these problems I am having with PostgreSQL on my linux machine

Answer (score 0):

You ran into an **important** security feature of **QubesOS**:  All data modifications are **discarded** on shutdown of a so called "*Qube*".  They are reset to their original state.
But there is the exception of data kept in some very special directories.
If you convince your data base packages to put their data into these directories, it will be preserved over reboots of your data base *Qube*:
Read [this documentation](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/bind-dirs/) for more information.